# mysql select date interval past week using year week

Tags: mysql

how to get data in pass 90 days from giving week.
I have a giving week `YEARWEEK("2020-04-12")`
when I query like this

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
where date_colum < DATE_SUB(YEARWEEK("2020-04-12"), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
```

I got result `null`.
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why are we using yearweek? Subtract the day of the week from the date to get the first day of the week (or use date_format)

Comment: I need to passing a date in week

Comment: I don't see that

Comment: `YEARWEEK("2020-04-12")` is not a valid input to `DATE_SUB`

Comment: how can I get interval 90 days from `YEARWEEK("2020-04-12")` ?